# Bash $@ equivalent in nushell

Tags: linux, nushell

I want to access all the arguments and run the same command on each argument in the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env nu

def main [ one, two ] {
    // echo each item in the argument list
}
```

How to achieve this in nushell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [Rest parameters](https://www.nushell.sh/book/custom_commands.html#rest-parameters):

```
def main [...args: string] {
    $args| each { echo $in }
}

> main one two three
╭───┬───────╮
│ 0 │ one   │
│ 1 │ two   │
│ 2 │ three │
╰───┴───────╯
```

`args` can be named whatever you want.  The only "magic" variable in that example is `$in`, which could be replaced with the non-magic form:

```
    $args| each { |item| echo $item }
```